# ActiveMQ execution failing on IBM i

Tags: activemq-classic, ibm-midrange

Has anyone installed/run ActiveMQ on IBM i and can help me with this? 
Either the process does not run or gives ZipException.

I downloaded ActiveMQ 5.16.2 from [ActiveMQ 5.16.2 (Apr 28, 2021)](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/) - Unix/Linux/Cygwin bundle
for installing on IBMi V7R3 and followed the official steps for installation mentioned on [Version 5 Getting Started](https://activemq.apache.org/version-5-getting-started.html) - 'Installation Procedure for Unix' section.

This is similar to installing on IBMi as mentioned in - [Installing activeMQ on IBM i5 V5R4](http://yiyujia.blogspot.com/2011/02/installing-activemq-on-ibm-i5-v5r4.html)

On running the command **./bin/activemq start**, the process starts but ends without actually running ActiveMq.
It shows below error on the console -

```
./bin/activemq: 001-0019 Error found searching for command whoami. No such path or directory.
```

[image: activemq start dump]

Also the command **./bin/activemq status** returns **ActiveMQ not running** .

When running the command **./bin/activemq console**, the process starts but gives the same whoami error and ends with ZipException.

[image: activemq console dump]

On Windows, I have been able to install and run successfully.

Has anyone installed ActiveMQ on IBMi and can help me with this?

Comment: IBM i OSS provides activemq 5.15.12 as a rpm with eventuel dependencies, see [here](https://ibmi-oss-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yum/README.html). Just installed it here inside a chroot env and can run activemq start|stop|status|console with no error

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the command

```
whoami
```

This is not a shell built-in, so you would need to add that package to your installation.

h/t to @nfgl for the pointer to the IBM OSS rpm repo. If you inspect their src.rpm, you'll see they patch the activemq script. Worth reviewing

SRC RPM calls for this dependency: coreutils-gnu

IBM iSeries Patch of bin/activemq:

```
    $ more activemq-activemq.patch 
--- a/bin/activemq  2020-03-30 18:50:50.000000000 +0000
+++ b/bin/activemq  2020-03-30 18:57:03.000000000 +0000
@@ -336,10 +336,14 @@
               -Dactivemq.data=\"${ACTIVEMQ_DATA}\" \
               $ACTIVEMQ_CYGWIN \
               -jar \"${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/bin/activemq.jar\" $COMMANDLINE_ARGS >> $ACTIVEMQ_OUT 2>&1 &
-              RET=\"\$?\"; APID=\"\$!\";
-              echo \$APID > "${PIDFILE}";
-              echo \"INFO: pidfile created : '${PIDFILE}' (pid '\$APID')\";exit \$RET" $DOIT_POSTFIX
-      RET="$?"
+              exit \"\$?\"" $DOIT_POSTFIX
+              RET="$?"
+              sleep 5
+              OS400_PID=`ps | grep -iE 'java|jFromPASE|jvmStartPase|qp0zspwp' | grep -v '\spgm-' | grep -vE '^\s+1\s' | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'`
+              rm -f $PIDFILE
+              qsh -c "/usr/bin/touch -C 1208 $PIDFILE"
+              echo $OS400_PID > $PIDFILE
+              echo "INFO: pidfile created : '$PIDFILE' (pid '$OS400_PID')"
    elif [ -n "$TASK_TODO" ] && [ "$TASK_TODO" = "stop" ];then
           SPID="`cat "${PIDFILE}"`"
           $EXEC_OPTION $DOIT_PREFIX "\"$JAVACMD\" $ACTIVEMQ_OPTS $ACTIVEMQ_DEBUG_OPTS \
@@ -384,7 +388,7 @@
         return 2
        fi
        ACTIVEMQ_PID="`cat ${ACTIVEMQ_PIDFILE}`"
-       RET="`ps -p "${ACTIVEMQ_PID}"|grep java`"
+       RET=`/QOpenSys/usr/bin/ps -p ${ACTIVEMQ_PID}|grep -iE 'java|jFromPASE|jvmStartPase'`
        if [ -n "$RET" ];then
          return 0;
        else
@@ -403,7 +407,7 @@
         return 2
        fi
        THEPID=`cat ${PID_STOP}`
-       RET=`ps -p $THEPID|grep java`
+       RET=`/QOpenSys/usr/bin/ps -p ${ACTIVEMQ_PID}|grep -iE 'java|jFromPASE|jvmStartPase'`
        if [ -n "$RET" ];then
          return 0;
        else
```